# Program Threads hanging when using a semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, semaphore

I have an issue setting up a critical section with a semaphore between 2 threads. I am using a semaphore to acquire(send) in my Customer thread and release in my teller thread. However when I run my program it is always hanging and I don't know why. I have tried several things and i am not sure what the issue was.

I am trying to use the deposit semaphore to set up a critical section with the customer thread and teller thread.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Threads {

// private int customerNumber = 0;
 private static Semaphore deposit = new Semaphore (0, true);



public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    final int customerThreads = 5;
    final int tellerThreads = 2;
    final int loanThreads = 1;

    Customer thr[] = new Customer[customerThreads]; // make 5 customer threads
    Thread cThread[] = new Thread[customerThreads]; // made 5 threads

    for (int i= 0; i < customerThreads; i++)
    {
        thr[i]= new Customer(i);
        cThread[i] = new Thread(thr [i]);
        cThread[i].start();

    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < customerThreads; i++ )
    {
        try {
            cThread[i].join ();
            System.out.println("Customer"+i + "joined from main");

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }

    Teller thr1[] = new Teller[tellerThreads];
    Thread tThread[] = new Thread[tellerThreads];
    for (int b = 0; b< tellerThreads; b++)
    {
        thr1[b] = new Teller(b);
        tThread[b]= new Thread(thr1 [b]);
        tThread[b].start();
    }

    LoanOfficer thr2[] = new LoanOfficer[loanThreads];
    Thread lThread[] = new Thread[loanThreads];
    for(int c = 0; c< loanThreads; c++)
    {
        thr2[c] = new LoanOfficer(c);
        lThread[c] = new Thread(thr2 [c]);
        lThread[c].start();           
    }               
    // TODO code application logic here
}



static class Customer implements Runnable
{
private int customerNumber = 0;
private int balance = 0;

Customer(int cn)
{
   this.customerNumber = cn;
   balance = 1000;
   System.out.println("Customer"+ customerNumber + "created");
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(200);
    deposit.acquire();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println("Customer"+ customerNumber + "created");
   // try

  }
   public void post()
    {

    }

 }

 static class Teller implements Runnable 
 {
 private int tellerNumber = 0;

 Teller(int tn)
 {
    this.tellerNumber = tn;
    System.out.println("Teller"+ tellerNumber +"created");
}

public void run()
{
    deposit.release();
 //        try
 //        {
 //            
 //           // deposit.release();
 //            
 //           Thread.sleep(100);
 //       // deposit.acquire();
 //        }
 //        catch(InterruptedException e)
 //        {
 //            deposit.release();
 //        }

    //System.out.println("Teller"+ tellerNumber +"created");
   }

   public void post()
   {

  }
 }

 static class LoanOfficer implements Runnable
 {
private int loanNumber = 0;
LoanOfficer(int tn)
{
    this.loanNumber = tn;
    System.out.println("LoanOfficer"+loanNumber+"created");
}
public void run()
{
    //System.out.println("LoanOfficer"+loanNumber+"created");
}
public void post()
{

}
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate semaphore with no permits as below:

```
private static Semaphore deposit = new Semaphore (0, true);
```

Hence when you try to call acquire, you wont get the permit to execute beyond and hence blocks. So try atleast having 1 permit so at a time only 1 thread can execute post you acquire the permit from semaphore. You could increase that later as well.

```
private static Semaphore deposit = new Semaphore (1, true);
```

Refer the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28%29)

Comment: I did that as you said and changed nothing else in my code but it is still hanging. Only when I added the semaphore did this happen.I wonder if my sleeping or something is wrong with my signal and acquire.

Comment: So as i said 1 is just example. Looking at code you have join and you release the permit in some other thread which is bad practise. Anyhow you should use private static Semaphore deposit = new Semaphore (customerThreads, true); Although this would work but remember you will just release 2 permits of semaphore from Teller which is not good as well. So please think about your design.

Comment: So this to me seems producer consumer problem. What you are after is inter thread communication. So If you check on google you will get loads of example on the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will but isn't this similar what I am currently doing, atleast I still have to code the semaphores with those permits right?Many of the producer consumer examples use synchronize and wait() etc which I am not allowed to use. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have to do it this way according to my project , cannot use synchronized or wait() etc only what I have shown.If I continue this route, can I still use your semaphore permit advice? thank you!

Comment: I have to do it this way according to my project , cannot use synchronized or wait() etc only what I have shown.If I continue this route, can I still use your semaphore permit advice? thank you!

Comment: I have to do it this way according to my project , cannot use synchronized or wait() etc only what I have shown.If I continue this route, can I still use your semaphore permit advice? thank you!

Comment: I can only use 2 teller threads as rules, and I will queue the customers to make sure they don't try to over run the teller and wait. This can work correct using an array etc to make the customers wait?I think i have to queue the customer objects not the actual threads at that point.